# Include other js in webpack vs Vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to inject a script file to web pack but when run i have a error
Uncaught ReferenceError: Vue is not defined
HOw i can do it
In Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import nqt from './nqt.js';
//Vue.use(nqt)
```

In nqt.js

```
vm = new Vue();
console.log(vm);
```

Thank for read!

Comment: In the first glance I feel, you need to import vue in nqt.js as well. Can you please share your webpack configuration and project structure?

Comment: Thank for reply, i have import vue  and it work. Now i want access vm var from qnt.js in my main.js but it say vm is not defined. https://hackmd.io/s/B1lQ7z_WZ

Comment: You need to export vm to use it in other modules and import it the modules where you want to use it.

Comment: Take a look at this article to understand how es6 modules work. http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

Comment: I don't know how to export it. I export and i have error. My code : https://hackmd.io/s/B1lQ7z_WZ

Comment: check my answer or updated hackmd https://hackmd.io/s/B1lQ7z_WZ

Comment: This work! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using es6 modules in your project. And to use any module inside another modules you need to first import it.

Add this line on top of your `./nqt.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue';
```

Now if you want the vm defined in `./nqt.js` to be used inside other modules, you need to export it here like this.
    var vm = new Vue();
    export default vm;

And then import it inside `./main.js`

```
import vm from `./nqt.js`
```

In order to get how it works take a look at http://2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html